# Printing pattern in unix using awk

Tags: unix, awk, printing

need to print log file as per the field data present in file using awk. Sample log file data--

```
Joe,4
Tony,2
Peter,5
```

Desired Output
(First Field with c<0>---c--

```
Joe,c0,c1,c2,c3
Tony,c0,c1
Peter,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please always try to show your efforts in your post, also wrap your sample in code tags too.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {printf $1 OFS;k="";for(i=1;i<=$NF;i++){printf("%s%s","c"k++,i==$NF?ORS:OFS)}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`, perhaps the shortest possible...

```
$ awk -F, '{f="";while($2--)f=FS"c"$2f;print $1f}' file

Joe,c0,c1,c2,c3
Tony,c0,c1
Peter,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{printf $1; for(i=0; i<$2; i++)printf("%sc%d",OFS, i ); print ""}' file
Joe,c0,c1,c2,c3
Tony,c0,c1
Peter,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4
```

***Explanation***

```
awk 'BEGIN{
      FS=OFS=","                       # set i/p and o/p field separator
     }
     {
      printf $1;                       # print first field
      for(i=0; i<$2; i++)              # loop from 0 to value in second field
            printf("%sc%d",OFS, i );   # printf format string
      print ""                         # finally print newline char
     }
    ' file
```